# SDK Manager in Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

I download and install android studio 3.0.1 from developer.android.com. but that package did not have any sdk manager. before I had android studio 2.3.1 and I had sdk 25 for that . now I uninstall 2.3.1 and install 3.0.1. 
which version of SDK I should download for android studio 3.0.1 and how I should install it? I have a picture from my gradle in android studio 3.0:

[image]

Comment: Android sdk path has been set in android studio?

Comment: Studio already configures sdk path for you.What error are you getting?

Comment: hi lib4. the path is for previese version of studio.

Comment: hi Justcurious. i sent a picture of my studio and gradle file . it says i should install build tool 26.0.2 and sync project. but when i connect to internet it says can not find that package.

Comment: Check this link and download you dependency . http://www.creativepulse.gr/media/blog/2014/20140320-android-google-maps/figure2.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

from file menu open

settings>Appearance & Behaviour>System Settings>Android SDK

click on SDK Tools, check on show package details 
this will display the details in android SDK Build-tools, you can check "on" 26.0.2 to download it.

make sure you have internet connection, if any problems appears while downloading this package, then you have to be sure that proxy settings is correct if you are using it.

another solution is by trying to build the project with newer build tools that you have already downloaded.

Comment: _Appearance & Behaviour_ ... seriously? why not as a hidden link under Help->About?

Comment: How counter intuitive. Which druggard is coding it that way. In the IDE look and feel you have put Android SDK!